# How to split my treeview single row into 2 r 3 rows in ASP.NET (Web Application)

Tags: asp.net

**EXAMPLE:** some bla bla goes here

1.Kalaiselvan(**Parent node**)

1.1 kalai is from india and he lives in tamilnadu(1988-2011),klaisewkkladslh kjkhlghjg khkgl.

1.2.scales related to single book some thing goes like that and huge text goes here

2.kannan(Parent node)

2.1 kannan is a gud man and he is a brother of kalaiselvan jghkljg hkjlgh tyugkjhg ghjgglkl.

2.2 there are some problems to split the nodes of single treeview rows into 2 r 3 rows.

I need to split that 1.1,1.2,2.1,2.2 nodes into atleast 2 r 3 rows..

**Note: Am using sql server as back-end..these nodes r fetched from sql server oly**

Thanks.